# Clearly wrong close review audit - what action to take?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I'm failing a non-zero amount of review audit question. Some of them are borderline which are a teaching moment for me. Others are clearly incorrect, and the question is totally inappropriate for Stack Overflow.

[This is the failed review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2121049)

Here is a question, in all its glory, that I voted to close:

> **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110360/where-can-i-find-the-bootstrap-buttons-that-are-styled-for-social-logins**
>
> I saw on Hacker News one time that have "styles" for bootstrap
> buttons. These styles include Facebook color, Twitter's color,
> Google's color.

The review system told me that there 'was nothing wrong with this question' which I'm pretty sure is a mistake.

Should I just move on and ignore it or is there anyway to flag this question as not appropriate for a review audit test? Or is there other action that is appropriate to take?

Comment: Ah, TIMEX. Why am I not surprised?

Comment: At least you got a whole lot of meta rep from it :D +1

Answer (score 12):

> Should I just move on and ignore it

Pretty much.  If you end up with enough audit failures to get yourself review banned and one or more of them you feel are errors on the part of the audit, not you, then you could [contact the team](https://stackoverflow.com/help/other) and explain it; they could reverse it if they want.  If you don't fail enough to be banned I don't think it's worth bothering with though.

> Is there anyway to flag this question as not appropriate for a review audit test?

Yes and no.  What you can do here is go to the question itself and vote to close it, if you feel it really should be closed.  (Or vote to reopen if you feel it should be re-opened and the audit disagrees).

Questions are chosen for audits based on a random selection from those that meet given criteria.  It looks for posts with more than X votes, with no close votes, no past closures, and possibly some other stuff and says, "Here, this is clearly a good question based on all of these objective measurements."  Sometimes they're just wrong though; this question is an example of that.  It should have been closed and it just wasn't; I disagree that it should have been upvoted but it was.  By voting to close it will cease to meet the criteria and is no longer eligible for being an audit post.

(Note: the question has since been closed, likely due to the attention of your post here.)

Comment: Even a single downvote will make a question ineligible for use as an audit, so it's pretty easy to remove stuff from the pool.

Comment: I suggest only dipping from recent stuff, since our standards have been stricter in recent months or years.

Comment: We look at questions from the past 30 days, @djechlin.

Comment: I hope that this question getting 8 upvotes was a freak accident, caused by the obscure tag.

Comment: @Pekka웃, if you look at the top answer you'll see a +50 bounty was awarded. Still crazy that the question got 8 upvotes, but the bounty helps explain why.