# Reopen Votes - Do I miss something? "STOP! Look and Listen."

Tags: discussion, review, closed-questions, disputed-review-audits

During review of "Reopen Votes" found interesting task. Course, after reading new "version" of the question, I've clicked "Leave Closed" and got message "**STOP!...**"

I'm talking about **[this question!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892264/how-to-do-a-chromecast-api-white-list-url-page)**!

Then, after reading again and again still don't get it, why this question wasn't closed! Can't see any code, can't see any efforts by OP and to be honest I'd CLOSE this question again.

The irony is "I understand" button in upper-right corner of the task, which I really don't. So that dilemma brought me here after a while, trying to find clarification to this problem.

Do this question follow all the SO rules about writing good, informative, easy-to-understand question?

I don't think so, but maybe I'm missing something important in rules or just do not understand clearly what's purpose of SO.

**UPDATE:** Course, I know about **Skip** button. I'm skipping everything what I'm not familiar with or not sure does its content follow rules, but this case was clear to me - **LEAVE CLOSED** or **CLOSE** (IMMEDIATELY). That's why I was confused with **STOP!** message.

Just need your opinion, does it break any rule about writing good question? What do you think?

Comment: I can't say; I don't know enough about Chromecast to conclusively say that this question lacked effort.

Comment: @Makoto, we're talking about OP efforts. What has he tried so far? According to my understanding, questions with no showing at least minimal effort to get solution are not good. Even homework questions are more informative than this. Well, also, I can't be 100% sure, that's reason why I'm looking for solution here or any suggestion by more experienced reviewers.

Comment: I learned that you needed to supply one of two URL's to the receiver thing.

Comment: First, there's a difference between questions asking for code and asking for explanation. The latter type tends to be much more useful.

Comment: Second, if you don't know if a question should be closed, **skip**. What kind of proof of effort would you like here?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 proof of effort is overrated. "proof of effort" are merely words the community uses to close the questions they don't want.

Comment: Review tests are chosen automatically from 'good' questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180417/clearly-wrong-close-review-audit-what-action-to-take

Comment: @JanDvorak, Partially agree, but still there are thousands of other questions like this closed. Where's that line to separate good and bad questions. Some questions belong to SU, SF, WA, etc. I now, partially we all make own rules but there must be LOWEST and HIGHEST limit of good appropriate question.

Comment: @Danack, thanks, seen that but its irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: Link to the review in discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2649597

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you missed was a good reason for closing this question. Let's review:

1. Readable question, easy enough to understand for anyone even passingly familiar with the topic.
2. Descriptive title.
3. Reasonably scoped.
4. On-topic.
5. Answerable (indicated by the fact that it was answered if nothing else).
6. Not a duplicate.

There is no "didn't show enough effort" close reason, because that's impossible to quantify - "enough effort" for many critics would involve solving the problem one's self and then quietly moving on to the next one; while often a good practice, this doesn't exactly make for a thriving Q&A site.

When you're reviewing questions in the Reopen queue, ask yourself: "is this question bad for the site?" If you can easily think up a good reason for "yes" - one that you could potentially relay to the author of the post in person without feeling like an idiot - then "Leave Closed"; otherwise, reopen.

Comment: Either I'm missing something or the logic in your last paragraph is upside-down: if you can't easily think up a good reason for the question to be bad for the site, you should reopen it, not leave it closed.

Comment: Heh, yeah... Need more coffee.

Comment: +1, sure, agree with you, mostly. "Effort" is most important reason for closing questions from my angle of view. People must push at least minimal effort to answer the question by own selves. You cant just see something or hear something and ask "why that works like that" or "how I can do the same thing". I dont blame people for not knowing something, but even a bad try is some effort. However, thanks for your answer, wanted to hear some good reasons, and certainly you provided some.

Comment: If you feel a post demonstrates insufficient effort for your taste, then down-vote it @Wh1T3h4Ck5. That's why the guidance for down-voting starts with, "This question does not show any research effort"... Although note that even *there*, the guidance specifies "none" not "insufficient".

Comment: You're probably right, downvoting makes more sense than closing question. Thanks a lot @Shog9.